# Is it possible to order posts with the number of Facebook likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

If I have a Facebook like on my blog posts, is it possible to order posts based on the number of Facebook likes?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is described here http://peterbending.com/wordpress/how-to-order-posts-by-number-of-facebook-likes/